# Using ReactNative app how to forward the user to his native Map application on the phone?

Tags: react-native

I have an app written in react native. I am looking for a solution where the user is clicking on a button which has coordinates X and Y, then the user is prompted to open a native app from his phone supporting navigation(Google Maps APP or the iOS Map) ?

Thanks
V

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a [MapLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html) on iOS or a [Geo URI](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents) on android:

```
const mapUrl =
  Platform.OS == "ios"
    ? `https://maps.apple.com/?ll=${latCoord},${lngCoord}`
    : `geo:${latCoord},${lngCoord}:`;
```

Then you can use the [Linking API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking) to pass this URL via React Native, assuming you are using an `onPress` function:

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'

onPress = async url => {
  await Linking.openURL(url)      
}
```

Since `openURL` returns a promise you should set it up to be asynchronous if you want to handle any logic after the link opens.